# Java RegExp: Which is faster: series of simple ones or one complex?

Tags: java, regex, performance

I am writing a program that has to strip pretty long strings of quite a lot of rubbish. I do that using regular expressions, and as my program is rather sensitive in terms of speed, I need to know which of the solutions is faster: Using a number of consecutive relatively simple regular expressions, or using a single but quite a complex one?

Best regards, 
Timofey.

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing the actual expressions. (There is no general answer to this question anyway, but it is easy for you to simply test the performance of either approach.)

Comment: And not just the regexes; the text you match on can also make a huge difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to benchmark this stuff to be sure, and be sure to blog your results. I suspect one big regex will be quicker than many small ones, but I'm curious to see what you find out.

The `java.util.regex.Pattern` class is pretty complex and I don't pretend to know what optimizations it performs. I do know regexes compile into a graph, so an obvious one would be to combine overlapping paths. The more variations you stuff into a single expression, the more such opportunities arise. It may also reduce the number of passes over the input data.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that only a (well-written) benchmark can answer this, and also that one cannot know what sort of optimizations happen depending on the implementation. For example, perl creates a trie data structure out of many alternatives: see for example how `perl -Mre=debug -cwe '/abc|adec|adfe|abcdgd|adfxe/'` works out.  A trie runs much more quickly than just testing one after the other. It sounds like java isn't smart enough to do that though.

Comment: Indeed. There are languages (and implementations) (much) better suited for bulk text processing than standard Java. This does beg the question whether any of the open-source Java regex frameworks (like [GNU regexp](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/gnu-regexp-docs/) are any better.

Answer (score 3):

As many of you suggested, i tried it and here are the results:

After joining some of the RegExps that i used consequently into one, my execution time almost doubled (from 10 seconds for processing 1000 strings to 18 seconds for 1000 of the same strings).

So, basically, it turns out that sequentially removing as many symbols as you can, so as to make the remaining string as short as possible for the next regexp to clean, is faster than long regexps.

PS. Unfortunately, i couldn't post the regexps themselves, as they get corrupted by the code highlighter.

PPS: Here are some of the regexps i used sequentially:

`s = s.replaceAll("<span STYLE=\"color:[\w|\d|\(|\)|\,]++\">", "");
s = s.replaceAll("</{0,1}\w++>", "");
s = s.replaceAll("<img SRC=\"/gif/", "");
s = s.replaceAll("(width|height)\s{0,}=\s{0,}\"{0,1}\d{1,}\"{0,1}", "");
s = s.replaceAll("align=\"\w++\"", "");`

Then I combined them together by putting each one in brackets and placing the | between them.

Comment: Thank you for reporting your findings. Could you post your regexes anyway? If you can't get the formatting right, maybe a moderator can.

Comment: That matched my findings too, even with JDK 8.  I was suspecting a large one would be much faster, but smaller ones seem much quicker.